# How can I reopen this question?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I have [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/474938/276972) closed by a moderator. The close banner says

> This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers.

I'd like the question and I hope the question is reopened.

The question is on explaining the meaning and origin of different names indicating independent variables.
I tried to edit the question in several ways such as limiting the question range. But it couldn't be reopened.

I'm also ready to convert it to community wiki question but it doesn't have any option to convert it.

Do you have any suggestions to change the question in the format which can be accepted?

Comment: I found the question interesting and made comments (and specifically comments, not an answer, because what I could offer fell a long way short of the answer you were asking for). But it was closed as lacking in focus because you asked several things at once, and that closure makes sense to me too. The issue is not that it **cannot** be reopened, as people with enough reputation can certainly vote to reopen, but so far no such votes.  Equally a moderator could reverse the decision, which hasn't yet happened. Your editing it remains possible, but not sufficient to ensure re-opening.

Comment: Indeed, you have edited it several times since it was closed, but you have made just minor changes, and I don't think these are anywhere near enough for re-opening to be likely, but that is just one guess.

Comment: I generally agree with Nick Cox. But perhaps the question might be acceptable as a community wiki?

Comment: @mkt CW is not a mechanism for allowing questions that do not meet site standards.  I have not voted to reopen the question because (in its current form) it is far too broad: it asks us to "organize the origin of terms and the field of study." That may be interesting and suitable on other sites, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: @whuber Fair enough. I vaguely remember a CW question dealing with lists of terms and thought it might be similar, but closing also seems entirely reasonable.

Comment: @mkt CW is weird.  Different SE sites use it differently.  I have reserved it for questions that are on topic, clear, as focused as possible, but obviously will--or at least potentially can--receive multiple correct answers.  That's primarily requests for references.  I think other mods take a similar approach.

Comment: @whuber How about I limit the list of terms I'm curious and ask for the answer for the limited list? Does it satisfy the condition?

Comment: I am sympathetic to that approach.  There is a problem, though, which is already apparent in your current list: these terms are not synonymous.  Consider instead offering one term (along with a clear definition for it) and ask for its synonyms and their origins.  Even that is skirting the edges of what is officially on topic, but we generally don't close such questions when they are so clearly posed and relevant to statistics.

Comment: @whuber I edited my question. Let me know if it's still not suitable. Thanks.